# Delay a member variables type definition till another class inherits from it

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, crtp, stdtuple

I am trying to declare an member variable type to be something that a deriving class controls- without transferring the type as an template.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>  
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

template<class DERIVED_TYPE>
struct haveChildren
{   
    const std::tuple<int, DERIVED_TYPE::innerContext > myChildren;

    haveChildren(int a, char b) : myChildren(5, DERIVED_TYPE::innerContext{ a, b }) {}

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& streamReceiver, const haveChildren<DERIVED_TYPE>& streamSender)
    {
        int myInt;  int myChar;
        std::tie(myInt, myChar) =   std::get<1>(streamSender.myChildren);

        return streamReceiver << "My int is " << myInt << " my char is " << ((char)myChar);
    }
};

struct haveChildrenCharAndInt : public haveChildren<haveChildrenCharAndInt>
{
    typedef    std::tuple<char, int> innerContext;

    haveChildrenCharAndInt() : haveChildren<haveChildrenCharAndInt>(10,'x') {}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << haveChildrenCharAndInt();
    return 0;
}
```

That do of course not compile- but I hope you understand what I want to do.

It can be done by transferring the types as template arguments like this:

```
template<class DERIVED_TYPE,typename A,typename B>
struct haveChildren
{   
    const std::tuple<int, std::tuple<A, B>  > myChildren;

    haveChildren(int a, char b) : myChildren(5, std::tuple<A, B> { a, b }) {}

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& streamReceiver, const haveChildren<DERIVED_TYPE,A,B>& streamSender)
    {
        int myInt;  int myChar;
        std::tie(myInt, myChar) =   std::get<1>(streamSender.myChildren);

        return streamReceiver << "My int is " << myInt << " my char is " << ((char)myChar);
    }
};

struct haveChildrenCharAndInt : public haveChildren<haveChildrenCharAndInt,char,int>
{
    typedef    std::tuple<char, int> innerContext;

    haveChildrenCharAndInt() : haveChildren<haveChildrenCharAndInt,char,int>(10,'x') {}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{    
    cout << haveChildrenCharAndInt();
    return 0;
}
```

But that solution is not good because the types the class should have as member variables are classes and they are created afterwards.

Do any of you know a design or trick that would make it possible to have a member variable of a type not defined until a class inherits from it- without transferring the types as template arguments?

Comment: What do you mean by *the types ... are classes and are created afterwards*? The types constituting `innerContext` need to be complete when you define `haveChildrenCharAndInt` so that the base class can contain an instance of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter your design a little bit and get it to work.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>  
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

// A helper class template to let you define the inner
// context of a derived type before the derived type is
// defined.
template <class DERIVED_TYPE> struct InnerContext;

template<class DERIVED_TYPE>
struct haveChildren
{   
   // Use the helper class template to get the inner context 
   // type of DERIVED_TYPE.
   using DerivedInnerContext = typename InnerContext<DERIVED_TYPE>::type;
   std::tuple<int, DerivedInnerContext> myChildren;

   haveChildren(int a, char b) : myChildren(5, DerivedInnerContext{ a, b }) {}

   friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& streamReceiver, const haveChildren& streamSender)
   {
      int myInt;  int myChar;
      std::tie(myInt, myChar) =  std::get<1>(streamSender.myChildren);

      return streamReceiver << "My int is " << myInt << " my char is " << ((char)myChar);
   }
};

// Define the inner context of haveChildrenCharAndInt before
// haveChildrenCharAndInt is defined.
struct haveChildrenCharAndInt;
template <> struct InnerContext<haveChildrenCharAndInt>
{
   using type = std::tuple<char, int>;
};

// haveChildrenCharAndInt is now simplified.
struct haveChildrenCharAndInt : public haveChildren<haveChildrenCharAndInt>
{
   haveChildrenCharAndInt() : haveChildren<haveChildrenCharAndInt>(10,'x') {}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   cout << haveChildrenCharAndInt();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very nice, I had a vision that something like that could work- but I could not make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer the inner context as a type trait:

```
template<typename Type>
struct inner_context;
```

and use it in the base class as:

```
template<class Derived>
struct base {
    using children_type = typename inner_context<Derived>::type;
    const std::tuple<int, children_type> children;

    base(int a, char b) : children(5, children_type{ a, b }) {}
};
```

Then whenever you define a new type, you declare the specialization for that type:

```
struct derived;

template<>
struct inner_context<derived> {
    using type = std::tuple<char, int>;
};
```

and finally the type itself:

```
struct derived : public base<derived> {
    derived() : base(10,'x') {}
};
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef6c3577f4a1d741)

Comment: We are all interconnected, aren't we?

Comment: This is the best explanation for type traits I have read seen so far- I have read some examples but did not really get it and could not see how it would work here. I have learned a valuable skill. Thank you very much.